# How does DirectShow decide between two codecs with the same merit value?

Tags: directshow, codec

Given two codecs with the same merit value, how does DirectShow decide which one to use through the 'intelligent connect' mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

It throws a dice.

Seriously the behavior is undefined, both decoders have chances to be taken first. In case of rejection, filter graph would try the other one.

Comment: Highly unlikely it is random. msdn actually mentions _some additional criteria_ is used ([see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704841/how-does-directshow-decide-between-two-codecs-with-the-same-merit-value/7835269#7835269)), but doesn't clarify it further. Even still, it would rather depend on which filter was loaded first or something similar than 'random' behavior.

Comment: Your answer makes no sense. Additional criteria don't apply to 99% of the filters out there (not even saying that it's Win 7 only!). Real order is dependent on the order `Filter Mapper` does enumeration, which in its turn is not documented and underfined for filters with the same merit. It is actually the order the registration come in registry, internal `RegEnumKey` call order will stipulate the filter order.

Comment: There is only one this which is possibly taking place (and again, undocumented): if the filter is registered with `MEDIASUBTYPE_NULL` it should be less preferred to another one with the same merit and defined subtype... You can use my Spy tool to check out details, if you are curious enough: Spy traces all `Filter Mapper` requests into log file.

Comment: Obviously you know more about the subject than I do. Care to update your answer and share this extra knowledge? I was only referring to msdn.

Comment: The whole point here is that it's not something you can rely on, even knowing more details on internal design. If one's app really cares which decoder is in use, it should either add it manually, or at least have some control over this process (such as blacklisting unwanted decoders).

Answer (score 0):

The [intelligent connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd390342%28VS.85%29.aspx) msdn page sheds some light on this.

Starting from **Windows 7, a new system is used**, and the merit system is only used as a fallback when no filter is found after searching for one using the new approach.

> Starting in Windows 7, DirectShow has a list of preferred filters for
>   certain media subtypes. If there is a preferred filter for the media
>   type that is being rendered, the Filter Graph Manager tries that
>   filter next. An application can modify the list of preferred filters
>   by using the [IAMPluginControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319756%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) interface. Changes to the list affect
>   the application's current process, and are discarded after the process
>   ends.

In case [the merit system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd390674%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is used, the msdn page **only** mentions the following:

> Then it tries them in order of merit, from highest to lowest. (It uses additional criteria to choose between filters with equal merit.)